# Discover which form button triggered submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form, I have two submit buttons.

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save as draft"/>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Start sending" />
```

Now before submitting the form back to the server, I want to perform specific tasks depending on which button was clicked.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if submit equals save
       task 1;
    elseif submit equals send
       task 2               
}
```

How do I check which button was pressed?

Comment: I'm sure that you can improve on the title of this question.

Comment: add click handlers for both buttons

Comment: @aleksv just go ahead and post that up so I can +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
    $("form").data("submit-button", this.name);
});

$("form").submit(function() {
    var button = $(this).data("submit-button");
    ...
});
```

Add a click handler on your submit buttons that stores the name. Then extract that name in your submit handler.

Comment: Oh wait, I thought you were merely copying the name of the button the the button element itself, not to the form. But even then: why not put the logic in the click handler, instead of the form's submit handler?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Because then the logic does not run when you submit the form through other methods like pressing ENTER.

Answer (score 5):

If it were me I would do this a little bit differently. I would do something along the lines of -

```
<button type='button' id='formSave'>Save as draft</button>
<button type='button' id='formSend'>Start Sending</button>

$('#formSave').click(function(){
    //submit form
    //task 1
});

$('#formSend').click(function(){
    //submit form
    //task 2
});
```

Im just basing my answer off of your button names and whatnot but it sounds like you want to do something simliar to this.

Comment: I think the second one should use `'#formSend'`

Comment: This breaks non JavaScript support. Please write unobtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: @Raynos raises a good point.  Also remember that forms can be submitted without pressing buttons - like pressing return while an input element is focused; some browsers will pseudo-click the closest button, others will submit the form without pseudo-clicking a button.

Comment: @Raynos This is unobtrusive JS. I think you mean you should let the page degrade. But OP has already mentioned that he's got a JS step in the middle of sending the data to the server.

Comment: @Raynos: I think it's pretty clear that the application being built by the OP has Javascript as a pre-requisite.

Comment: @JohnP Isn't unobtrusive JS where you upgrade a valid HTML only page with JavaScript behaviour? Maybe the term is "Progressive Enhancement" @TomalakGeret'kal that's a really poor assumption. Your basically saying the OP isn't clever enough to handle task 1 and task 2 on the server aswell as the client.

Comment: @Raynos, yup, that's progressive enhancement. Obtrusive JS when you use the ugly `onclick` handlers.

Comment: @JohnP Ok "UnObtrusive JS" = keep html & js seperate. "Progressive enhancement" = JS only enhances existing functionality. Got it.

Comment: I think its a safe assumption that the OP is looking for an answer in js or jq when asking a question tagged `javascript` and `jquery`. Using server side scripts doesn't mean that you're not clever...

Comment: @HurnsMobile is there any harm in writing progressive enhancement? I always assume that the asker has a solution working without JavaScript and just wants me to upgrade his HTML only solution with some shiny JS. I'm not suggesting you show him how to do this non-JavaScript solution, I'm merely saying you shouldn't change his HTML so his non-JavaScript solution breaks.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input').each(function(n) {
  $(this).click( function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');

    if (name === 'save') {
       // do stuff
    }else if (name === 'submit'){
       // do some other stuff
    }
   }
});
```

of course you can also use a switch statement.

If the job that you want to perform is complex and way different, you should consider using 2 different forms

I hope this answers your question

**EDIT:**

```
$('input:submit').click(function(n) {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if (name === 'save') {
       // do stuff
    }else if (name === 'submit'){
       // do some other stuff
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Where do you check that the button was clicked?

Comment: Now you're adding event handlers to _every_ `input`, even if it won't do anything. Seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: @Ibu optimise it to $("input").click

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but I'd +1 if you made that `$('input:submit')` :)

Comment: @JohnP yes would do that if the input type was submit but in this case he has the type as button

Comment: @ibu, ummm no, the types are `submit`

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using the approach of HurnsMobile, but if you absolutely need one function to handle both the buttons you can use the jQuery event object to detect buttons,

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    if(event.target.name == 'save') {
        // do save task
    } else if (event.target.name == 'send') {
        // do send task
    }  
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that works. I believe some browsers set `event.target === form`